# Chrome Extension to change DOM when user clicks in the browser button

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a extension to Chrome that changes all the occurences of a name in the webpage. (For example, if the page has the word "that" it changes it to another name).

The idea is to make this change when the user clicks on the browser button.

My problem is that it don't make the changes! I have no idea of what I'm doin wrong.

Here's the manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "App Name",
  "description": "App description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "jquery.ba-replacetext.min.js","background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "App name",
      "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And here's the background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var state = document.readyState;
    var carregou = false;
    var matches = document.body.innerText.match(regex);

if (state == "interactive"|| (!carregou)){
 $("body *").replaceText( /That/gi, "" );
 var regex = /That/gi;
 matches = document.body.innerText.match(regex);
 if(matches){
    alert("Reload the page (f5)");
 }else{ 
    alert("All changes done! :D");
    carregou = true;
 }
}
});
```

I did one that changes the page without clicking in the browser button, and it works. Here's the code:

```
{
  "name": "App Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "App description.",
  "content_scripts": [
   {
   "matches": ["http://www.facebook.com/*"],
   "js": ["jquery.min.js","jquery.ba-replacetext.min.js", "script.js"],
   "run_at": "document_end"
   }
   ]
}
```

sript.js:

```
var state = document.readyState;
var carregou = false;
var matches = document.body.innerText.match(regex);
if (state == "interactive"|| (!carregou)){
 $("body *").replaceText( /That/gi, "" );
 var regex = /That/gi;
 matches = document.body.innerText.match(regex);
 if(matches){
    alert("Reload the pahe (f5)");
 }else{ 
    alert("All changes done! :D");
    carregou = true;
 }
}
```

Chrome Version: 23.0.1271.95 m on Windows 7
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1)**

Your background.js executes code in its [own generated html page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) world, A[s the architecture overview explains](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#arch), the background page is an HTML page that runs in the extension process. It exists for the lifetime of your extension, and only one instance of it at a time is active.

Hence, all the code is trying to changes all the occurrences of a name in the `background.html` page

You can achieve your functionality with [Programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) using same code

**Demonstration**

```
/* in background.html */
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                           {code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"});
});
```

**Case 2)**

You have completely injected script for all facebook URL's `"matches": ["http://www.facebook.com/*"],` instead of [Programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi), so it worked, not because of no [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#apiReference) in your manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "App Name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "App description.",
  "content_scripts": [
   {
   "matches": ["http://www.facebook.com/*"],
   "js": ["jquery.min.js","jquery.ba-replacetext.min.js", "script.js"],
   "run_at": "document_end"
   }
   ]
}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I missed that point. However, it's a little embarrassing but I still can't make it work. I did this: chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                           {file:"content.js"});
   
});

It seems that the code in the file isn't running. But anyway, I just post it here to give you a feedback. Thanks again! :D

Comment: ok , you forgot to register background page to manifest like this `"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },`